# How to escape regex in Java methods call in simple language in Apache's Camel Spring DSL (XML) route?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-spring-dsl

I have a `setHeader` tag in my route:

```
<setHeader headerName="timestampPart3"><simple>${header.timestampPart2.split("\\.")[0]}</simple></setHeader>
<log message="After: ${body} ${headers}"/>
```

I expect, it will split the String inside the timestampPart2 header and take the first element.

In fact, it just ignores the splitting:

```
timestampPart2=114128.0, timestampPart3=114128.0
```

So how I should implement regex escaping in Spring DSL? If for some reason it is impossible, how to work that around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set an `Exchange` message header you would need to use the `name` field and not the `headerName` field:

```xml
<setHeader name="timestampPart3">
    <simple>some-simple-expression</simple>
</setHeader>
```

Additionally you need to provide a raw `regex` expression for string `#split` method that will get sanitized (if needed) under the hood automatically by the OGNL - Camel parsing layer for you:

```xml
<setHeader name="timestampPart3">
    <simple>${header.timestampPart2.split("\.")[0]}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

> Note the single back-slack character escaping the `.` special character. In short, you should provide a regular expression without escaping control sequences as you would do when inputing the same regular expression through a compile `String` literal in Java ***(it is raw XML (input stream) after all)***